# Sort board backlog column

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to transition my team over to using boards to track work items.

Currently it seems the default ordering of backlog work items is oldest to newest created. I would like to be able to choose the reverse sorting without manually updating the backlog.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The ordering is by "Backlog priority". The higher a work item is on the backlog, the higher its priority. This is due to the basic assumptions of agile development to always work on highest priority items first (take the item on top).

When you add items to the backlog you can choose where to add it in the list (top, selected item, bottom). On boards you can configure if you just want to reflect the priority from the board or if you want to allow reordering.

To answer your question: No, you cannot just change the ordering direction.

Comment: Clarification: It's called "Stack Rank" in the Agile and CMMI processes, and "Backlog Priority" in the Scrum process

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort the rows in Backlog view but you CAN sort, by Title for example, in Work Items view.

Comment: Is. there a code or process steps you can share on how this can be achieved. The OP is looking for a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Backlog` tab at the top (next to `Taskboard`) and drag and drop work items.